# Need to install Java to use android studio?

Tags: software-installation, java, android

new Linux user here, I am using chaletOS. I'm trying to install and run android-studio.

After I try to run studio.sh, an error window pops up that reads: Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_121-b00: Java 1.8 or later is required. Unsupported Java Version: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_121-b

However I just installed the latest version of Java, it is now sitting in /Desktop/ in a folder labeled jre1.8.0_111

What am I missing here? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: can you put the output of  the command `java -version`

Comment: You need to install openjdk 1.8 not jre 1.8. Android didnt need java from oracle again.

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered the same issue recently

and i found the solution as :

---

```
$ sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list
```

and add these two lines:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
$ sudo apt-get update.
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

---

Check if it is installed properly.

```
zeus@debian:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

---

Make as default.

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the lastest android studio, i didn't install jdk and it worked.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk):

> A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2 and
>   higher, and this is the JDK version we recommend you use for your
>   Android projects. To use the bundled JDK, proceed as follows:
>
> 1. Open your project in Android Studio and select File > Project Structure in the menu bar.
> 2. In the SDK Location page and under JDK location, check the Use embedded JDK checkbox.
> 3. Click OK.